# how to use networking when building docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

i want to build a docker image of my app. the build process (tests) requires other services (db). seems like my app can't connect to the db

i managed to replicate the problem using simple and small images.

dockerfile (it just tries to reach web endpoint)

```
from alpine:3.10.2
run wget web:8080
cmd ["sh"]
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: tutum/hello-world
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - web
```

during `docker-compose up` i got

```
wget: bad address 'web:8080'
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c wget web:8080' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

how can i access other container during build process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `network` as host in your compose:

```
build:
     network: host
```

and access it using `localhost:port`

**Example:**

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: tutum/hello-world
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  app:
    build:
     context: .
     network: host
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.10.2
RUN wget localhost:8080
CMD ["sh"]
```

run `web`:

```
docker-compose up -d --build web
```

run `app`:

```
docker-compose up -d --build app
```

output:

```
Building app
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.10.2
3.10.2: Pulling from library/alpine
9d48c3bd43c5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:72c42ed48c3a2db31b7dafe17d275b634664a708d901ec9fd57b1529280f01fb
Status: Downloaded newer image for alpine:3.10.2
 ---> 961769676411
Step 2/3 : RUN wget localhost:8080
 ---> Running in f021283ab323
Connecting to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
index.html           100% |********************************|   478  0:00:00 ETA
Removing intermediate container f021283ab323
 ---> aae07c08a119
Step 3/3 : CMD ["sh"]
 ---> Running in e81d9401db71
Removing intermediate container e81d9401db71
 ---> 6c217a535c7d

Successfully built 6c217a535c7d
Successfully tagged docker-test_app:latest
docker-test_web_1 is up-to-date
Creating docker-test_app_1 ... done
```